# How to find the amino acid that is bound to a tRNA with the anticodon?

Tags: molecular-biology, homework

> 1. What amino acid is bound to a **tRNA** with the following anticodon: $5^{\prime}$ A U G $3^{\prime}$
>
> > The answer is *Histidine*.
>
> 2. What amino acid is attached to the **tRNA** with the following anticodon $5^{\prime}$ A G C $3^{\prime}$
>
> > The answer is *Alanine*.

I also referred to this image below but unable to get the answer. Can anyone please explain how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each tRNA brings a single amino acid and add them to the growing peptide strand. The tRNA has an 'anticodon' which recognizes a codon on the mRNA code. How this occurs: [image: Always visualize.]

How to figure it out:

- You have to find out the complementary bases. With DNA, A is complementary with T, and C is complementary with G. However, we are working now with RNA! It's similar with RNA, with one exception: in RNA, U (uracyl) is used instead of T, **so A is complementary with U**. C is still complementary with G.
- Notice that the 5'-3' anticodon is antiparallel to the codon (one is 5'-3', the other is 3'-5'). This means that to find out which amino acid is being added, you have to reverse the code found on the tRNA.

Your questions, let's go step by step:

> *1)* tRNA anticodon: AUG
>
> tRNA complementary strand would be UAC. Reverse to get the 5'-3'
> direction on the mRNA. The reverse of UAC is **CAU, which is His
> (histidine).**

and

> *2)* tRNA anticodon: AGC
>
> tRNA complementary strand would be UCG. Reverse to get the 5'-3'
> direction on the mRNA. The reverse of UCG is **GCU, which is Ala
> (alanine).**

You can also reverse first and complement second. The order does not matter, provided you do both. Always visualize the process, it helps tremendously.

Let's do a final exercise to see if you understand, but in reverse and with some extra thinking. *What are the tRNA sequences which bind to the mRNA strand ACUACAGUAUAC? What is the peptide sequence it will produce?*

mRNA: ACU ACA GUA UAC

We can use the translation table immediately; it is used to translate mRNA into peptides directly. We find out it produces the peptide: **Thr Thr Val Tyr**

Reverse mRNA:  CAU AUG ACA UCA

Complement it: GUA UAC UGU AGU

*(FYI: by convention, we always write mRNA in the 5'-3' direction)*

The tRNA anticodons which bring (i) **Thr** (ii) **Thr** (iii) **Val** (iv) **Tyr** to build the peptide chain are (i) **GUA** (ii) **UAC** (iii) **UGU** and (iv) **AGU**.

All of these sequences are written in the 5'-3' direction, as per convention. It's easy if you are careful and clear in your working :-)